# How to display dll's loading on a WPF start up splash screen?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking to create an application start up splash screen.

On that screen I'd like to display the application dll's as they are loaded in
(like you see on the Output window in visual studio when you run a project)

Does anybody know how I can do this?
Many thanks.

Comment: Something you should know: [When exactly are assemblies loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914692/when-exactly-are-assemblies-loaded) – so if you think you need that feature make sure everything is pre-loaded, but then again: why take a performance impact for loading an assembly if it possibly is never needed?

Comment: @Dirk : link you provide basically access all loaded assemblies in app domain. however from question it appears that Saoirse looking for some mechanism which would notify back as an when dll are loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by creating the main application as the "Splash" screen.  I only have 1 DLL in the below instance, but you could have several.  In the Main Window, instead of a grid, I use a DockPanel with a progress bar docked at the bottom with IsIndeterminate="True", a text block named status also docked at bottom (I could not get binding to work for some reason), and an Image (not docked, fills upper part of window)...

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Wait for screen to be shown before continuing...
        ContentRendered += AppLoader;
    }

    private void AppLoader(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // we want to make sure this only happens once...
        ContentRendered -= AppLoader;
        // use a background worker...
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        // allows us to update the status...
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgw.ProgressChanged += Bgw_ProgressChanged;
        // here is where we hide the main window and continue with the application...
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += Bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        // load dll's, check security, etc.
        bgw.DoWork += Bgw_DoWork;
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    [STAThread]
    private void Bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result != null)
        {
            // show main window and hide this "Splash Screen" window
            Window window = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance((Type)e.Result);
            Hide();
            window.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Unable to find local resources.", Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    public void UpdateUI()
    {            
        DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate (object parameter)
        {
            frame.Continue = false;
            return null;
        }), null);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    }

    private void Bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Status.Text = $"{e.UserState}";
        UpdateUI();
    }

    private void Bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker Bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        e.Result = null;

        ConfigFile Cfg = new ConfigFile();
        if (Cfg.Count==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "ERROR:  XmlCfg missing or not accessable.", Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        if (AppDLL.IsAdmin)
        {
            // load dll...
            Bgw.ReportProgress(0, "Loading...");
            e.Result = AppDLL.GetWindow("./TAC.dll", "AppWindow");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "ERROR:  Admin credentials required.", Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below :

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
      currentDomain.AssemblyLoad += new AssemblyLoadEventHandler(MyAssemblyLoadEventHandler);

static void MyAssemblyLoadEventHandler(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args) {
      var assemblyName = args.LoadedAssembly.FullName;
      /* use this name to pass to your splash screen */

   }
```

Comment: Note that – depending on your application – this event might hit only long after the splash screen is gone.

Comment: did you checked that ? I think event should fire an and when dll is loaded into app domain

Comment: You are correct, but assemblies are loaded lazily, i.e. only when a method referencing an assembly is called. So the load might happen much later during the execution of the application long after the splash screen is gone.

Comment: hmm , i see your point. I did quick search around and looks this been already discussed here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532820/how-do-i-report-progress-on-loading-assemblies-into-the-current-appdomain-in-ne)